# What setting in visual studio forces indentation on new line after the enum keyword?

Tags: visual-studio, autoindent

What I would like is for a new line to come down to the same indentation, so that I can place my curly brackets at the same indentation as the enum keyword.

What happens instead is that the next line is indented.

Here are my indentation settings.

[image: settings]

Here is a GIF of what is happening.

[image: GIF of auto indentation]

Comment: Update: I have reinstalled, reset all settings, and nothing is changing this option.  I'm using VS 2017

Comment: That didn't work, and it would be pretty weird if it did.  I want it to not indent, so that would mean checking an indention off.